# binary operator "<"

Tags: binary

Consider this expression as a "selection" control structure on integer "x": 
0 < x < 10,
with the intention that the structure returns TRUE if "x" is in the range 1..9.

1. Explain why a compiler should not accept this expression. (In particular, what are the issues regarding the binary operator "<"?
2. Explain how a prefix operator could be introduced so the expression can be successfully processed.

Comment: what language? this is valid in Python.

Comment: Having been helping my wife with her CS homework - the way this question is phrased means it is most definitely homework, and a c/p of the homework question at that.

Comment: i can think of the precedence from left to right , so this would read as (0 is less than x)..not sure why that would be a problem..thanks!

Comment: its not a hw...its a past question from a comprehensive exam that  i am trying to solve
http://www.sci.csueastbay.edu/mathcs/comps/csexams/cs_f06.html#THEORY

Comment: So what you want to do is rephrase the question so the answer is related to the part you *don't* understand, and so it's not *just copied from your textbook*

Comment: -1, this is obviously a copy-paste from an assignment. No problem in asking help with homework, but simply copy-pasting it verbatim without any explanation of where you're stuck (and hoping for a spoon-feed answer?), is not the way to learn new things, IMO.

Comment: Badly tagged;  while an operator with two operands *is* a binary operator, that hardly justifies the tag, since the term applies more generally to other things.  It cannot be determined what he compiler will do unless the language is specified; now that would be a *useful and relevant* tag!

Comment: Hint: Think about what the *type* of (0 < x) is. You are then supplying that type to the left hand side of the second `<` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the hint..

so for part a..the compiler would try to parse somthing like FALSE/TRUE < 20 which is not the desired result

for part b, i can think of if (X>0 && X <10) ..but not sure how to introduce a prefix operator in the existing expression.

btw, this is my first time using stack overflow for math qs and i am impressed with the involvement of its community...and agree with everyone :)

Comment: Depending on the language, the syntax could be allowed and transformed into a `(0 < x') && (x' < 10)` construct, where `x'` is `x` evaluated once before the expression (to avoid double side-effects when evaluating x twice). Considering that `a < b` produces a true/false result, and would normally not then be compared with another number, the compiler would be able to detect this special case.

Answer (score 2):

1. The expression doesn't read like a binary operation, but resembles a ternary operator.  There are 3 parameters to what you have stated with 0 < x < 10, as 0,x, and 10 are all tokens for the parser to interpret, no?  If you meant for a pair of < to form a ternary operator that is a different story.
2. One could view the ternary operation as getting split into a pair of comparisons and each comparison is evaluated with the results combined by an AND operation.  That would make sense 
   to my mind.

Comment: < *is* a binary operator, the expression is not a binary *operation*.

Comment: Ok, corrected terminology in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the return types of the < operator.

Comment: And specifically, how the expression is evaluated, and in what order.  Write down the series of steps that the compiler must take to evaluate the expression, and the value at each one of those steps.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why this mysterious compiler couldn't transform that expression into:

```
x > 0 && x < 10
```

Comment: I could tell you why, but that would give the answer to the homework!  Your expression is not semantically the same; at least not in C or C++

Comment: @Clifford, Who said this is C or C++?

Comment: @Clifford - Please explain why. *(By the way I simply meant to write this in a syntax that most people would understand. I make no claims at being an expert.)*

Comment: @JS Bangs: No one, but the answer is language dependent, so the question is unanswerable unless and until we are told.  My point was that ChaosPandion sees "no reason", but one reason might be because it is a C++ compiler.

Comment: I think that is the point of the question, one might think they are equivalent, but in many programming languages they are not, so the compiler could not "transform" it, you have to write semantically correct code (i.e. it has to mean to the compiler what you intended) not just syntactically correct.  I have added an answer that perhaps explains the problem without giving away too much.

Answer (score 0):

The code is syntactically valid in C and C++, but is unlikley to be semantically correct in either language.  We are left guessing the language at this time.

When I compiled it as C++ VC++2008 issued a warning which rather gave away the answer, so you might try that.  Here's my test code:

```
int main()
{
    volatile int x = 0 ;
    if( x < x < 10 )
    {
        x = 5 ;
    }
}
```

When C compilation was used it accepted it silently.

As to why it may be a problem, the compiler interprets the expression as (0 < x) < 10.  Hint: what is the type of the left-hand side of the second "<" ?

However this may not be the answer you are looking for, because it seems that you must be referring to a different language if the compiler should not accept it.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is happy with it. You can even give it the right semantics:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class Int
{
public:
    int x;
    Int () { }
    Int (int z) : x (z) { }
};

class BoolRange
{
public:
    bool value;
    int left;
    int right;

    BoolRange() : value (false) { }

    BoolRange (bool v, int l, int r)
        : value (v), left (l), right (r) { }

    operator bool ()
    {
        return value;
    }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Int i)
{
    return out << i.x;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, BoolRange b)
{
    return out << b.left << '[' << b.value << ']' << b.right;
}

BoolRange operator< (Int l, Int r)
{
    return BoolRange (l.x < r.x, l.x, r.x);
}

BoolRange operator< (Int l, BoolRange r)
{
    return r.value
        ? BoolRange (l.x < r.left, l.x, r.right)
        : BoolRange ();
}

BoolRange operator< (BoolRange l, Int r)
{
    return l.value
        ? BoolRange (l.right < r.x, l.left, r.x)
        : BoolRange ();
}

BoolRange operator< (BoolRange l, BoolRange r)
{
    return l.value && r.value
        ? BoolRange (l.right < r.left, l.left, r.right)
        : BoolRange ();
}

// Test driven development!
int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        Int v = rand() % 100;
        Int w = rand() % 100;

        if (Int(1) < v < w < Int(10)) // Look here!
        {
            assert (1<v.x && v.x<w.x && w.x<10);
        } else
        {
            assert (1>=v.x || v.x>=w.x || w.x>=10);
        }
    }
}
```